# Laravel Error: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuex

I'm getting the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

I've seen many posts on this error but nothing has helped.

This is my laravel **controller**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Messages;
use App\User;
use Auth;

    class MessagesController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            // We need to be able to see each user that has corresponded with this particular user. And only display them once on their users list.
            // Hence we made a 'correspondence_id' so we can filter that later on in vue.

            // Grab current user.
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

            // Grab all messages related to this user.
            $messages = Messages::where('send_id', $user_id)->orWhere('receive_id', $user_id)->get();

            foreach($messages as $message) {

                // for each message we want to grab the first and last name of the person we received or send the message to.
                if($user_id == $message['send_id']) {
                    // User_id is my id, so we don't want that name.
                } else {
                    // We want to grab their name.
                    $user = User::where('id', $message['send_id'])->first();

                    // Add this user to the message.
                    $message['firstname'] = $user['firstname'];
                    $message['lastname'] = $user['lastname'];
                    // Add profile_img url.
                    $message['profile_img'] = $user['profile_img'];
                    // Add id of user you are speaking to.
                    $message['correspondence_id'] = $message['send_id'];
                }

                if($user_id == $message['receive_id']) {
                    // User_id is my id, so we don't want that name.
                } else {
                    // We want to grab their name.
                    $user = User::where('id', $message['receive_id'])->first();

                    // Add his first and last name to the message.
                    $message['firstname'] = $user['firstname'];
                    $message['lastname'] = $user['lastname'];

                    // This should have the image of the profile who is receiving the image (not the other user).
                    $currentUser = User::where('id', $message['send_id'])->first();
                    $message['profile_img'] = $currentUser['profile_img'];

                    // Add id of user speaking to you.
                    $message['correspondence_id'] = $message['receive_id'];

                }

            }

            return compact('messages');

        }

        public function store(Request $request,$receive_id, $message)
        {
            // Grab current user.
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

            $messages = new Messages();

            $messages->fill($request->all());
            $messages->send_id = $user_id;
            $messages->receive_id = $receive_id;
            $messages->message = $message;

            $messages->save();

            $text = "Message stored";

            return compact("text");

        }

    }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('/sendmessage/{receive_id}/{message}','MessagesController@store');
```

**Db structure:**
`id`, `send_id`, `receive_id`, `created_at`, `message`
The id and created_at are filled in automatically.

Post Request from Axios (vuex)

```
sendMessage({ commit }, payload){
        var receive_id = payload.receive_id;
        var message = payload.message;
        console.log(payload)

        axios.post('/sendmessage/'+receive_id+'/'+message, {
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(commit);
            console.log("success");
        }).catch((response) => {
            // Get the errors given from the backend
            let errorobject = response.response.data.errors;
            for (let key in errorobject) {
                if (errorobject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    console.log(errorobject[key]);
                    this.backenderror = errorobject[key];
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

The data is correctly being sent to the request, and when I run it in vue I see this error in the console:

```
app.js:26133 POST http://mysite.local/sendmessage/2/test 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: Please add your entire routes file. I'm pretty sure there's another route conflicts with this one

Comment: How are you sending the request?

Comment: @Devon The request is sent an axios request from vuex. However I've also tried going to the url directly (with the correct information in url)., and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add the code of how you initiating the request

Comment: Do you have a route like `Route::get('/sendmessage/{anything},'...`

Comment: @Otto well, show how you make the request... I asked for a reason.   Just visiting that page wouldn't be a POST request, so that makes sense.  It seems odd that message is a route parameter here...

Comment: @Devon I added how I make the request above, sorry it is late here! Thanks for the help (it is an axios post request from vuex).

Comment: @Otto, so you're actually showing a different error there.  You have a 500 error in your AJAX request, not a 405.  Seems like the route is working, but you have an error in your controller possibly.

Comment: @Devon I've added my entire controller, but I can't seem to find an error:/ can you?